# Making two rasters align with GDAL

Tags: python, alignment, raster, gdal, geotiff

I'm trying to align one raster to another using GDAL Warp in QGIS. Once I have this perfected, I will use the Python GDAL wrapper in a script. I've seen other threads about alignment issue which stateit's important use the reference image's extent coords, cell resolution and the `-tap` argument to force the second image to align. I ran this:

```
gdalwarp -s_srs EPSG:32630 -t_srs EPSG:32630 -tr 0.25 0.25 -r near -te 511711.9928 
6328998.9708 514192.6233 6331359.4866 -of GTiff -tap <path-input> <path-output>
```

But the output is still slightly off:

[image]

The dimensions of the reference image are 9923 x 9442 and the dimensions of the output image are 9924 x 9443. I want these to be the same, with the same cell resolution. They must overlap perfectly for conversion to numpy arrays later.

Is something obviously wrong? I'm aware of the Align Raster tool in QGIS, but I want this done in GDAL so I can adapt to a Python script. Thanks.

These are the data from the original rasters. I'm trying to match the one with the lower resolution.
[image]

Comment: If you're trying to match the input with lower resolution, why do you specify a resolution of 0.25 instead of 0.22706? The extent you use also doesn't neatly match that the resolution of 0.25.

Comment: The input extent from GDAL warp matches exactly the extents of 1), which is what I'm using as the reference image. Pretend 0.25 is actually 0.22706.

Comment: But you used 0.25, which is incompatible with that extent. So it makes sense that the output doesn't align well. Perhaps only the top-left corner will be, but the rest will be off if you do it like this. I don't understand the idea behind this. I would either match the reference image exactly, or warp both to a new common grid.

Comment: Yes. that's what I'm asking. How do I "match" the reference image exactly, or warp to a new common grid?